# Attach image in the email body using mail or mailx in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix, mailx

I want to attach an image in email body using the `mail` or `mailx` from shell script. `mutt` and `sendmail` utilities is not available and I dont have privileges to install those.

`uuencode` is also not available

First I tried sending the HTML content using mailx using the below command and it didnt work. It just send the raw data with html tags to the mail

```
export body="<html><header><title>This is title</title></header><body>Hello world</body></html>"
echo $body | mailx -S "MIME-Version: 1.0" -S "Content-Type: text/html" -vvv -s "test mail" -r sender@xx.com reciever@yy.com
```

I tried append-headers with the option -a and it didnt work since -a is meant for attachment

And also tried with below command and it just attaches the image and not visible in the body.

```
mailx -s "test mail" -r sender@xx.com reciever@yy.com < Capture.PNG
```

Can anyone help me with the correct way to send a email with picture in the body

Comment: "I want to attach an image in email body ..." What does this mean? There is no such thing. There is attachments, and there is HTML messages. There is no "attaching in the body".

Comment: which implementation of mailx/mail ? what mta is being used if it is not sendmail ?

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to send attachment is to use command like:

```
uuencode Capture.PNG Capture.PNG|mailx -s "test mail" -r sender@xx.com reciever@yy.com
```

Comment: I need the image in the body of the mail and also the `uuencode` is not available

Comment: @sparker, the image will be in the body of the mail, but visible as attach. And you can install uuencode (or ask sysadmin)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest answer:

```
 mail -s "the subject" -a attachment.xyz you@email.com < body.txt
```

If that doesn't work for you, use multipart MIME. c.f. [this post on Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/388580/how-to-add-an-attachment-to-a-html-email-in-unix) for an example.